# The device token has expired or the application is unregistered from notifications

Tags: notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, pushwoosh

After sending and receiving some notifications using **Pushwoosh**, for no reason I'm receiving this error in Pushwoosh `Push History` and nothing is delivering to the cellphone...

The error is : **The device token has expired or the application is unregistered from notifications**

**Note:** I'm using the free account in both websites (GCM Console & PushWoosh)

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case renewing the **GCM Server Key** solved my problem
Just go to your [GCM Console](http://console.developers.google.com) and from the `API Manager` page click on `Credentials` sub-menu and create a new Credentials of type `Serve Key`
And then Copy the `Key` to your android API Key in your `PushWoosh` panel.